# Problems parsing JSON -- ajax request sending as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, github, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to connect to the github api using javascript. I have a generic github function that does a call to a github uri.

```
function githubRequest(endpoint, method, body) {
  // console.log(github_token);
  var baseUri = "https://api.github.com";
  var fullUri = baseUri + endpoint; // endpoint is like /repos/username/repo/contents/path
  // set up the request
  $.ajax({
    url: fullUri,
    type: method,
    beforeSend: function(request) {
      request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + github_token);
      request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    },
    data: body,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("SUCCESS");
      alert("Filed added");
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("ERROR");
      alert("Something went wrong ... check console");
    }
  });
}
```

`github_token` is defined in another file.

Right now I am testing this using a `PUT` method, and I am trying to create a file on my repo.

More info here under the "Create a file" section: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/

Here is the `body` that I send along.

```
{
    "message": "Added files",
    "committer": {
        "name": name,
        "email": email
    },
    "content": base_64_content
}
```

Then I call my function. I try to upload a `README.md` file as an example.

In my console for chrome, I see two requests (I assume one is the preflight one and one is the actual one). The preflight one succeeds, the second one doesn't.

[image]

For some reason in the second request, the request payload is as follows:

`message=Added+files&committer%5Bname%5D=John+Doe&committer%5Bemail%5D=johndoe%40gmail.com&content=base64Content%3D`, where `base64Content` is the actual base 64 content.

I have two questions then.

Firstly, if the preflight request succeded, why did this one fail?
Secondly, why is it sending as non-json. Github response is

```
documentation_url:"https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file"
message:"Problems parsing JSON"
```

Comment: It might be expecting `body` to be stringified, because it can't send an object. The pre-flight check probably works because the structure of the message is ok, but when it tries to parse the json it fails

Comment: You are absolutely right. When I changed `data: body` to `data: JSON.stringify(body)`, it worked. Thank you

Comment: I have posted this as an answer so you can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expecting body to be stringified, because it can't send an object in an ajax request.

`data: JSON.stringify(body)` instead of `data: body`

The pre-flight check probably works because the structure of the message is ok, but when it tries to parse the json it fails.